# Syntax for defaulting to current time for Google Directions API

Tags: json, google-maps, parsing, google-directions-api

I'm trying to parse this URL and I'm wondering if anyone could tell me what to put in for the `departure_time` parameter so that it defaults to the current time:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=25broadyway&destination=pennstation,ny&departure_time=????current&mode=transit
```

I've tried: 
current, 0, time.now....I can't figure it out

Comment: By default it is now.

Answer (score 0):

From the Google APIs:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

***departure_time*** specifies the desired time of departure as **seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC***.
Example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&key={API_KEY}&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit

EDIT:
Try something like this method to get your *departure_time* in seconds:

```
private static string GoogleMapsDepartureTime(DateTime localTime)
{
    DateTime inceptionDateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 00:00:00");
    DateTime departureDateTime = localTime.ToUniversalTime();
    TimeSpan departureTimeSpan = departureDateTime - inceptionDateTime;
    double departureTimeSeconds = departureTimeSpan.TotalSeconds;

    return departureTimeSeconds.ToString().Split('.')[0];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there was no accepted answer or feedback so I'll take a crack at it. You should write "now" and it will give you the departure time to the nearest second.

Source:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: It says "time.now", not just "now". Is that supposed to be a comma?

Comment: Mea culpa.  I thought it was intended as a comma, but it could certainly be "time.now.", which is indeed different.